# JSON Pasing - how to?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I don't know how to parse a JSON if start with jsonArray instead jsonObject.
There's the JSON code.

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "title":
    {
     "rendered": "Apple apologises and fixes security flaw"
    }
 },

 {
   "id": 2,
   "title": 
    {
     "rendered": "Trophy hunting removes good genes and raises extinction risk"
    }
 }
   ...
]
```

I don't know how to get the JSONArray length. such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < JSONArray.length(); i++)
{
  JSONObject JSONObject1 = JSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
  int id = JSONObject1.getInt("id");
  string title = JSONObject1.getString("rendered");
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My answer is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject= jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
    JSONObject jsonInner= jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
    string title = jsonInner.getString("rendered");
}
```

Comment: why it has down rating?

Comment: I don't know who down rated it, but I still haven't tested your code. Thanks for your rapid answer @Munir .

Comment: @Wendy post your logcat error and update post with what you have done

Comment: Ok, it working, I am just missed a comma in the json string. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your json value is in this string variable : `json`

```
String json = "your_json_data";
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
    JSONObject titleObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
    String rendered = titleObject.getString("rendered");
}
```